# format the DateTime in an inputField

Tags: visualforce, datetime, formatting

- Is there a simple way to display the **dateTime** in an **inputfield** using
  an alternative **dateTime Format**?
- Or is there an easy way to display a **datepicker** when clicking in a
  normal **textfield** input?

Answer (score 3):

To use the Salesforce datepicker on an input field:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
          <apex:inputText size="10" id="datefield" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(true, this, false);" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You will need to use API Version 29.0 on your VF page though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java script date picker. Visit the link below for java script code.

http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.format() method or jQuery DatePicker - https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/